# Perl Command line - perl -pi -e

Tags: perl

I am trying to find and replace a string in a xml document

This is the code I am using:

```
perl -pi -e s/xmlNamespaceAware=\"false\"">"/xmlNamespaceAware=\"false\"">""<"Alias">"hostname"<"/Alias">"/g
```

Error:

```
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s/xmlNamespaceAware="false">/xmlNamespaceAware="false"><Alias>webtctdm1.ecorp.cat.com</Alias"
```

If I remove the / in  it works fine.

Also is there anyway I can write `"<"Alias">"hostname"<"/Alias">"` on a newline oppose to the same line as `xmlNamespaceAware="false">`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what shell are using? Windows's or something sh-like?

Answer (score 4):

Make your life easier and pick a delimiter other than `/` when dealing with HTML/XML.

With newline literal:

```
perl -pi -e '
s{xmlNamespaceAware="false">}
{xmlNamespaceAware="false">
<Alias>hostname</Alias>}g' *.xml
```

With newline escape character:

```
perl -pi -e '
s{xmlNamespaceAware="false">}
{xmlNamespaceAware="false">\n<Alias>hostname</Alias>}g' *.xml
```

Both do the same.

Comment: Also see [the answer from TLP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9826206) how to avoid repeating the string with [`\K`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28%3f%3c%3dpattern%29-%5cK).

Comment: Can I get some help with this 
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;

print "Please enter virtualhost 1 - Example - ucisha.rd.cat.com:";
my $virtualhost1 = <>;
system("ssh -t host \"sudo su - root -c 'perl -pi -e s/xmlNamespaceAware=\"false\">/xmlNamespaceAware=\"false\"><Alias>$virtualhost1<\/Alias>/g /tcserv
er/springsource-tc-server-node/UCISjvm/conf/krh.xml'\"");

-bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
-bash: -c: line 0: `perl -pi -e s/xmlNamespaceAware=false>/xmlNamespaceAware=false><Alias>akdljadlk'

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `\K` escape character for convenience. It will preserve the preceding string, much like a look-around assertion. I am also using `#` as the delimiter for the substitution regex to avoid having to escape slashes.

```
perl -pi -e 's#xmlNamespaceAware="false">\K#\n<Alias>hostname</Alias>#g'
```

Comment: Can someone help with this.
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;

print "Please enter virtualhost 1 - Example - ucisha.rd.cat.com:";
my $virtualhost1 = <>;
system("ssh -t wast1.ecorp.cat.com \"sudo su - root -c 'perl -pi -e s/xmlNamespaceAware=\"false\">/xmlNamespaceAware=\"false\"><Alias>$virtualhost1<\/Alias>/g /tcserv
er/springsource-tc-server-node/UCISjvm/conf/krh.xml'\"");

Answer (score 2):

That's a hopeless mess of a string. You've forgotten to escape some `"`, you've got a bare `/` in `</Alias>` which actually terminates the regex. Why not just use a single-quoted string to hold the whole thing?

```
perl -pi -e 's/xmlNamespaceAware="false">/xmlNamespaceAware="false"><Alias>hostname<\/Alias>/g'
```

Comment: Perfect .... I am new to this. Thanks for all your help! Is there a way to make the <Alias>hostname<\/Alias> write to a new line?

Comment: You could use a `\n` to embed a newline, but then you'd have to switch back to using `"` to whole the whole string, which leads to more escaping, blah blah blah. `\n` in single quoted strings won't be seen as a newline.

Comment: Dang it back to the drawing board .. Thanks

Comment: Nonsense, the single quotes are for the shell!

Comment: The substitution regex interpolates like a double quoted string, so `s/foo/bar\n/` *will* insert a newline, no matter the quoting.

Comment: This is what I am getting when I use it in a perl script.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it for you, but I have no Linux box to hand to try it. Using pipe as a delimiter for `s///` avoids the need for escaping slashes.

```
perl -pi -e 's|xmlNamespaceAware="false">|xmlNamespaceAware="false">\n<Alias>hostname</Alias>|g'
```